# In Visual Studio Code xlwings open excel raises Exception has occurred: com_error (-2147352567, 'Exception occured.', (0, None, None, None, 0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, xlwings

When running this piece of code

```
import xlwings
import time
excel_app = xlwings.App(visible=True)
excel_book = excel_app.books.open(r'c:\temp\x.xlsx')
time.sleep(10)
excel_book.save()
excel_book.close()
excel_app.quit()
```

in Visual Studion Code Python Debugger
i receive the following exception:

```
Exception has occurred: com_error (-2147352567, 'Exception occured.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352565), None)
File "C:\Users\sopremium\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.8\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x7.py", line 36799, in __call__ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(0, LCID, 2, (13, 0), ((12, 1),),Index
File "C:\git\x\y\excel_test.py", line 4, in <module> excel_book = excel_app.books.open(r'c:\temp\x.xlsx')
```

Running the same code standalone from command line python console is working fine.

Strange thing is it used to work in visual studio code too but stopped suddenly and I don't know why.

Comment: Of course first thing I checked out was if VSC uses the same version of python as I use in command line. This is exactly the same version.

Comment: -Have you run this code in the cmd terminal outside VS Code? Can it run?

Comment: I've run this code in the cmd terminal outside VS Code and it runs. I've run this code also from Notepad ++ and it runs too.

Comment: -How do you run your code? Have you installed python2 and python3? It is recommended that you reinstall the required modules in the python environment you are currently using.

Comment: Python 3. I suspect the problem is related to the VSC debugger confirmation some how since I reinstalled xlwings module and still no change

Comment: -Since in VS Code, python's debugging function is provided by python extension, it is recommended that you try to reinstall the python extension.

Answer (score 0):

OK - it seems that this was my unexperience. [I toggled the checkbox "Raised Exceptions" in "Breakpoints" section (bottom left corner)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYZzB.png) in the past so it stopped on the "Raised Exception" as I (unintentionally) requested.

But it was only **RAISED**. Later in the code in was handled but I even didn't try to check it because I saw [a big message in the VisualStudioCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjj0N.png) which made me confused.

The solution was just to turn off the checkbox [Raised Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQpDM.png).
The exception of course was raised as earlier but it was handled later without breakpoint and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off the checkbox 'Raised Exception' in BREAKPOINTS section and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).